# RF transmitter and multiple receivers to led on/off control

Tags: gpio, led

I would like to control multiple RF receivers to turn on/off LED. Can you please let me know is there any cheap generic RF transmitter and multiple receivers to achieve this using raspberry pi?

Answer (score 1):

Search [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00E594ZX0) or Google for `nRF24L01+ 2.4GHz Wireless Transceiver` - There are plenty of tutorials online. I have used this to communicate between arduinos and my Pi

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could use rf24 transievers. There are fairly cheap. If I recall they where about 7.00 for both of them. There are other places that sell them cheaper.